# Modifications on parent not persisted without explicit flush from parents repository

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

With `spring-data-jpa 2.0.8.RELEASE`

I have a `@OneToMany` related entity pair. Let's say `King` & `Peasant`. I wanted to have a logic where when a peasant is updated, this would also update the kings `@LastModifiedDate` value manually. I do something like this;

```
@PreUpdate
@PreRemove
@PrePersist
void updateParents() {
    Date now = new Date();
    BaseEntity container = getParent();
    while (Objects.nonNull(container)) {
        container.setUpdateDateTime(now);
        container = container.getParent();
    }
}
```

and this works well, meaning it does update all the parents up to the king (the table structure is really messy with 5 depth from king to the lowest serf), the problem I am having is, the modifications on parents are not persisted at all. I have a service like following;

```
@Transactional
public void update(String kingId, String peasantSeqNo) {
    Peasant peasant = peasantRepository.getPeasant(kingId, peasantSeqNo);
    peasant.setNobility(false);
    peasantRepository.save(peasant);
}
```

In above code, the `@PreUpdate` annotated `updateParents()` method is triggered, and king's update timestamp is updated, still after the transactions end, this change is not persisted. I can trigger this persistence with an explicit `kingRepository.flush()` but I want it to be done automatically, just with the modification of the parent.

The linkage between King-Peasant is as follows;

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = REMOVE)
private List<Peasant> peasantry;
```

and

```
@JsonBackReference
@MapsId("kingId")
@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_KING", referencedColumnName = "ID_KING", nullable = false)
private King parent;
```

This is somehow an issue with my utilization of JPA, but cannot find the exact reason & a solution, can you give me any input on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting a limitation of JPA (implementations).

When the event gets triggered the JPA implementation already decided which entities it is going to persist, thus your changes don't get picked up.

This behavior is actually defined as not being defined in the JPA specification:

> In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not invoke EntityMan- ager or query operations, access other entity instances, or modify relationships within the same persistence context[46].[47] A lifecycle callback method may modify the non-relationship state of the entity on which it is invoked.
>
> [46] Note that this caution applies also to the actions of objects that might be injected into an entity listener.
>
> [47] The semantics of such operations may be standardized in a future release of this specification.

So you need to move this behavior away from the JPA Listeners into your business logic.

Comment: I understand the point, but what I cannot wrap my head around is that, while `kingRepository.flush()` does trigger the detection of the change, but with `peasantRepository.saveAndFlush(peasant)` I cannot seem to trigger this behaviour. Shouldn't the flush in either case be universal so that parent modification should be picked up as well? Both flush calls are done before entity event call.

Comment: With `saveAndFlush` you probably trigger two flushes. One upon the call to `saveAndFlush`, which triggers the events. Then when the transaction ends another flush happens which now picks up the changed parents.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation, I need a `saveAndFlushThenAgainFlush()` haha. What if I put an `entityManager.flush()` at the end of all my transactions? Would it be too much? I was thinking the transaction end would include such a flush already, that is why I am confused why after `saveAndFlush` another flush happens and catches the changes.

Comment: `flushFirstFlushLaterFlushSomeMoreAndThenTryToCommitTheTransaction()` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcQBSRTf1Ho

Comment: [the one true flush I need](http://donatetosaveapet.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/fotolia_57973315.jpg)